# Column to create percentage of vote share

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

[image: DATA SET]

This is my dataset, here I want to create a fourth column showing the vote percentage.

- 1st column is the constituency
- 2nd column contains the candidates participated in the election
- 3rd column contains the number of votes he/she received in the
  election.

I want to create a 4th column whose the first-row value must be 329720/(329720+82332+19106) which is **0.764**.

Why first 3, because **V.P. SANU, Unnikrishnan & Abdul Majeed Faizy** were the persons who contested from **MALAPPURAM**

Likewise, I want to fill the 4th column having the vote share of each candidate from each distinct constituency.

Please help me with the R code for this task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)

# example data
df <- data.frame(
  constituency = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, rep = TRUE),
  candidate = sample(letters[1:5], 20, rep = TRUE),
  n_votes = sample(1:10, 20, rep = TRUE)
) %>% 
  # Just to ensure that there is only one obs per candiate-const-pair arrange(constituency, candidate) %>% 
  group_by(constituency, candidate) %>% 
  summarise(n_votes = sum(n_votes))

# Add vote share of a candidate per constituency
df %>% 
  group_by(constituency) %>% 
  mutate(pct_votes_per_constituency = n_votes / sum(n_votes))
```

Comment: Hi @stefan thanks for the input, but could you please edit your code with my column names. 1st column = CONSTITUENCY, 2nd column = NAME and 3rd column = TOTAL VOTES.   Thanks for helping